# Why my autoencoder doesn't give the reduced representation?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, pca, autoencoder

I'm trying to create a reduced representation of my data, that I will use in another model, and I proceed in the following way :

```
   input = Input(shape=(70,))
   encoded = Dense(output_dim=10, input_dim=70, activation='relu')(input)
   decoded = Dense(70, activation='relu')(encoded)
   autoencoder = Model(input, decoded)
   autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
   autoencoder.fit(df_values, df_values,epochs=10,batch_size=32)
   reduced_input = autoencoder.predict(df_values)
```

But there are still 100 columns in the `reduced_input`, they have modified values, i.e. not the same values that in the initial `input`, but still not reduced representation as I expected (like the components of PCA) even if I specified `output_dim=10`

I guess there is a mistake somewhere in my way of getting the reduced inputs, but I don't see where exactly. If you can help me to spot it, please!

Comment: when you down-vote the question, please explain what's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 7th layer then:

```
output_func_Layer_7 = K.function([autoencoder.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
                     [autoencoder.layers[7].output])
intermediate_output = output_func_Layer_7([X_train, False])
```

Comment: It is just an example. In your case you need to isolate first layer:

output_func_Layer_1 = K.function([autoencoder.layers[0].input, 'K.learning_phase()],
                     [autoencoder.layers[1].output])
intermediate_output = output_func_Layer_1([X_train, False])'
and then you draw it.